# Playing with llvm-py

Tags: llvm, osx-mavericks, llvm-clang, llvm-py

I was trying to get llvm-py to install on my OSX 10.9 and I got the following error when trying to install it.

```
% python setup.py build
Error: could not invoke ['llvm-config', '--version']
Try setting LLVM_CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/llvm-config
```

However, I don't seem to have `llvm-config` installed. Currently, `clang`, `llvm-gcc` and `llvm-g++` seem to be present by default on OSX. Should I be reinstalling it from source in order to be able to use llvm-config?

Answer (score 3):

The LLVM binary download (for example, [the one for version 3.3 is here](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#3.3)) comes with the `llvm-config` use tool, so you can use that. You don't need to rebuild it - just grab the archive appropriate for your OS from that page and unzip it.

Comment: The LLVM binaries on the llvm.org site do not appear to have RTTI enabled, which is a requirement for llvm-py. I had to compile LLVM from source according to the instructions on http://www.llvmpy.org/ under the Quick Start section.